# unique value from DB sqlite3 in process registration

Tags: python, sqlite, unique, registration

I am have a sqlite3 database users.db where table have named users and table have 2 rows: login and password.

```
users.db
users:
login | password
name 1|
name 2|
etc...... |
```

I am need to take data input by keyboard and if this data exists in the database ask input data again.

sample by python 2.6:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as db

#регистрация
print "reg for reg or enter your name"
_id = raw_input()
if _id == 'reg':
    name = raw_input("Choose your name: ")
    conn = db.connect('users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    player = c.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE users.login=?", (name,))
    #print player
    if player == True:
        print 'user exists'
```

Problem: this does not find the users name in the dabase, but the users name *is* present in the database:  `[(u'serg',), (u'sava',), ....]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c.execute()` does not return the result. You need to explicitly fetch rows. You only have one row here (a count) so use `.fetchone()`:

```
c.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE users.login=?", (name,))
playercount = c.fetchone()
if playercount[0]:
    print 'user exists'
```

Comment: ohh... this http://pastebin.com/eX5iky2f section after playercount = c.fetchone() if name doesnt exist into DB playercount =0. why dont work while playercount[0] !=0: ?

Comment: P.S. I am want upvote for your answer, but I am dont make this action, because i am have reputation < 15